# What do the small notes mean on 1st violin part

Tags: notation, violin

I’m playing first violin in my high school’s orchestra and came across a phrase with really small notes compared to the previous section. I suspect that it’s just showing me what the 2nd part is playing during my rest but I’m not sure. The image below is what I’m talking about

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct. Those small notes are **cues**, letting you know what is happening in another part during your rest.

In a high-school orchestra setting, it's not unusual for the conductor to ask you to play those cues. (But only play them if specifically asked to do so.)